# NesJS : using an interceptor for HTTP and WS

Tags: node.js, websocket, async-await, nestjs, interceptor

I created an interceptor to edit data after passing the controller.
It works with HTTP but not with WS.

This is the code of my interceptor :

```js
@Injectable()
export class SignFileInterceptor implements NestInterceptor {
  constructor(private fileService: FilesService) {}

  intercept(context: ExecutionContext, next: CallHandler): Observable<any> {
    return next.handle().pipe(
      map(async (data) => {
        const paths = getFilesDtoPaths(data);

        for (const path of paths) {
          const file = get(data, path);

          // Returns a promise
          const signed = await this.fileService.signFile(file);

          set(data, path, signed);
        }

        return data; // The data is edited and we can return it.
      }),
    );
  }
}
```

To use it for HTTP, I add the interceptor to the app module :

```js
providers: [
    AppService,
    {
      provide: APP_INTERCEPTOR,
      useClass: SignFileInterceptor,
    }
 ]
```

With this, all my HTTP requests are intercepted, and the response is correct.

I want to make the same thing with WS using the same interceptor.

```js
@WebSocketGateway({
  cors,
  allowEIO3: true,
})
@UseInterceptors(SignFileInterceptor) // Interceptor added HERE
@Injectable()
export class EventsGateway {
  constructor() {}

  @WebSocketServer()
  server!: Server;

  @SubscribeMessage('name1')
  async handleJoinRoom(
  ): Promise<string> {
    return 'john doe'
  }
  
  @SubscribeMessage('name2')
  async handleJoinRoom(
  ): Promise<string> {
    return 'john doe 2'
  }

  
}
```

When a WS is triggered, the code is executed, but the data is returned BEFORE the end of my interceptor execution.
The data is not edited.

I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

Change `map` to `mergeMap` or `switchMap` to handle the `async` execution of the code. `map` from RxJS is a synchronous method.

Comment: I don't understand. All my HTTP requests are slowed down if I add a promise with a setTimeout in the map function. The HTTP response is returned after the promise execution. With the map function, I do not have any problem with async code.

Answer (score 0):

This interceptor works well for HTTP and WS.
Another issue in my project caused the problem.

Sorry for the inconvenience.